# Why is bytecode JIT compiled at execution time and not at installation time?

Tags: compilation, distribution, jit, bytecode

Compiling a program to bytecode instead of native code enables a certain level of portability, so long a fitting Virtual Machine exists.

But I'm kinda wondering, why delay the compilation? Why not simply compile the byte code when installing an application?

And if that is done, why not adopt it to languages that directly compile to native code? Compile them to an intermediate format, distribute a "JIT" compiler with the installer and compile it on the target machine.

The only thing I can think of is runtime optimization. That's about the only major thing that can't be done at installation time. Thoughts?

Comment: if you update the VM will you have to recompile all your programs? or if you change any dependencies will you have to resolve which apps are affected and recompile them?

Comment: Also, you seem to massively underestimate. Being able to utilize all the state-of-the-art tricks of the CPU without compiling 20 executables is nice, but all this doesn't help help performance much if you have unresolved dynamicness in the program. The runtime optimizations of many JITs work to eliminate that dynamicness when all the data needed to do so is there - at runtime.

Comment: @james: Those are indeed valid points. But they are more or less the same for languages which compile directly to native code. Maybe I'm just looking for a way to have easier cross-plattform distribution for native apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often it is precompiled. Consider, for example, precompiling .NET code with [NGEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

One reason for not precompiling everything would be extensibility. Consider those languages which allow use of reflection to load additional code at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Some JIT Compilers (Java HotSpot, for example) use [type feedback](http://selflanguage.org/documentation/published/type-feedback.html) based inlining. They track which types are actually used in the program, and inline function calls based on the assumption that what they saw earlier is what they will see later. In order for this to work, they need to run the program through a number of iterations of its "hot loop" in order to know what types are used.

This optimization is totally unavailable at install time.

Answer (score 0):

The bytecode has been **compiled** just as well as the C++ code has been compiled.

Also the JIT compiler, i.e. .NET and the Java runtimes are massive and dynamic; And you can't foresee in a program which parts the apps use so you need the entire runtime.

Also one has to realize that a language targeted to a virtual machine has very different design goals than a language targeted to bare metal.

Take C++ vs. Java.

- C++ wouldn't work on a VM, In particular a lot of the C++ language design is geared towards RAII.
- Java wouldn't work on bare metal for so many reasons. primitive types for one.

EDIT:  As delnan points out correctly; JIT and similar technologies, though hugely benificial to bytecode performance, would likely not be available at install time. Also compiling for a VM is very different from compiling to native code.

Comment: Compiling pretty much means "translating" (from one computer language to another). There's nothing weird about compiling the output of a compiler.

Comment: @delnan No there is nothing weird about it sure, but fine, lets disagree on the complexity of compiling source to bytecode, to compiling bytecode to native.

Comment: It may be simpler (doesn't need to, though - the JIT parts of PyPy is a tremedous piece of genius, with multiple optimizations passes, its own bytecode format, etc. compared to its bytecode compiler, which doesn't need to check types and has a very high-level target format, for starters) but that doesn't make it less of a compiler.

Comment: @delnan Exactly, the JIT genius is nothing like compilation to me. We are getting to semantics that I don't think the OP intended here.

Comment: A JIT compiler is a compiler, as evident by the name. The way it gathers its input is different, and its output is executed right away, the languages it operates on are relatively low-level compared to the languages we use, but that's just details. All the internals, the things which make 99% of the JIT code, are the usual compiler stuff - analyse and optimize some internal representation, then generate code. Heck, many optimizations of "traditional" compilers are borrowed 1:1 by JIT compilers!

Comment: @delnan You have gotten me curious. Are those optimizations really described as compiling steps? Also I find the 1:1 hard to believe, they should already be implemented in the bytecode.

Comment: Compilers targetted towards VMs with JITs in fact leave most optimizations to the JIT, as it (if left alone) knows best what to optimize and how. At least, several Java and C# gurus have stated thus in various questions (I'll go search something concrete new). As for describing these as compilations steps, see e.g. the [PyPy blog](http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2011/03/controlling-tracing-of-interpreter-with_15.html).

Comment: @delnan "Compilers targetted towards VMs with JITs in fact leave most optimizations to the JIT" is the gist of my answer. Thanks for the link. I'd be happy if you find more relevant stuff.

Comment: Found something directly from the source, Eric Lippert (C# compiler team): "We [...] rely upon the jitter to do the heavy lifting of optimizations when it generates the real machine code." See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do.aspx

Comment: @delnan Thanks for your google fu. Seems the term compilation should be left to the first compiler, i.e. source to bytecode/native.